# Problemas ao alterar cor de linhas de um DataGrid em C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Estou com problemas ao alterar a cor das linhas do DataGrid, utilizo a seguinte função

```
int i = 0;
private void gvDados_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridRow rowContext = e.Row;
   if (rowContext != null)
   {
      string Situacao = dt.Rows[i]["Situacao"].ToString();
      if (Situacao.Equals("V"))
      {
         SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 104,0));
         rowContext.Background = brush;
      }
      else
      {
         SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 232,0));
         rowContext.Background = brush;
      }

      i++;
   }
}
```

Até então tudo bem, eu consigo ajustar as cores de acordo com o que quero, o problema em questão está quando eu utilizo a Scroll Bar Horizontal para descer os registros ou subir, então todas as cores são desconfiguradas aparecendo de forma aleatória. Como consigo resolver esse problema para as coisas não ficarem mudando ao rolar a scroll ?

Comment: Troca o evento que faz isso. `LoadingRow` vai ser disparado sempre que a linha estiver pra ser mostrada. O melhor é fazer depois que tiver populado o grid.

Comment: Entendi, qual evento você me indicaria? só consegui ter acesso ao DataGridRow rowContext = e.Row; de cada linha utilizando o LoadingRow

Comment: Mas você não precisa ter acesso a isso. O que vai acontecer nesse evento é que `e.Row` vai ser cada linha do grid cada vez que passar por aí. Você pode trocar essa ideia por um loop que passa por todas as linhas do grid.

Comment: Eu até mostraria algum código pra você, mas pra isso vou precisar abrir meu visual studio, criar um projeto WPF e testar o grid e estou sem tempo pra isso.

Comment: Então, a principio meu pensamento era esse criar um método capaz de ler uma grid linha a linha e alterar a cor, mas não consegui e o único jeito foi esse. vou dar uma pesquisada para tentar fazer desse modo